# Creating summary metrics/tables from list data

Tags: list, pivot-tables, metrics

I wondering if the below mockup is achievable within SharePoint. I have a list containing a number of checks, each which have a type and status (Pending/Complete/Approval Needed), is it possible to create the table at the top showing the totals?
[image]

The sort of thing in excel that would normally be achieved with a pivot table.

Any help/pointers most appreciated,

Thanks.